# Print via terminal without usblp

Tags: printing

I need to print in an Epson TM-U220PD model M188D for receipts (without cups support), I used to write in a terminal [text] > /dev/lp0 but now usblp is deprecated. I can use this printer enabling the usblp kernel module, but this action disable cups.

There's other way to print, maybe using CUPS? How can I find the new path to the printer?

Answer (score 2):

You can install it in CUPS as a raw device and then just `lp -d Epson [textfile]` (or possibly `cat text | lp -d Epson`) That's how I talk to my Eltron printers in EPL2.   In CUPS web interface it's under "Make: Raw", but in gnome-print it's "Choose Driver: Generic" then "Raw Queue".